# Spliting a string

Tags: c, string, split

I'm trying to make a program that should split a string in half but so far the program is printing out random letters when I want it to read what the user writes and use the string to split it in half. Another thing is that I'm not sure of is how to write the splitting into two (I have written that part as str/2).

```
int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Pick the program that should be executed:\n");
    printf(" 1. Split text\n Enter an option:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if (x == 1) {
    // testing example
        printf("Write the text you want to use:\n");
        char str[100];
        fgets(str, 100, stdin);
        printf("Input was: %s\n", str);

        char test[] = str;
        char *left;
        char *right;

        // first make a copy
        left = strcpy(test);

        // second locate the desired text and split in half
        right = strstr(left, (str/2));

        // third split the string
        *(right - 1) = '\0';

        // print the results
        printf("Original : %s\nLeft side: %s\nRight side: %s\n\n", test, left, right);

        // clean up
        free(left);
    }
    return main();
}
```

Comment: `strcpy(test)` that *doesn't* toss a huge warning from your compiler? [`strcpy`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) requires *two* arguments; not one. Turn up your warnings to pedantic levels and treat them *all* as errors.  I also don't understand how your compiler accepts `strstr(Left, (str/2))` as valid either. The middle of a string is typically found by pointer arithmetic using the base address of the string and the string *length*, typically found by `strlen`. I don't see where `strstr` is useful here at all.

Comment: could you please give us some examples :

Comment: The link to `strcpy` provided in my prior command documents *exactly* how to use it. The rest is forthcoming.

Comment: no I meant  Sketchup I need some example, because when the string has odd length how we will split it like "world" here 'r' where we will put it with left or right.

Comment: `str/2` divides the pointer in two, which is completely, totally not the thing you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a possible solution for your problem, and the problem was at **Point 1** where either you use **case A** or **case B**. The problem here is that you were using both `scanf` and `fgets` functions and since `scanf` doesn't consume the `\n` and `fgets` does you would always get an "empty" string (just a `\n`) in the `str` variable. So in **case A** you just use another `scanf` or in **case B** you need to consume that last `\n` and then read the string you want.

Besides that, for the spliting part I'm just using a simple [memcpy](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_memcpy.htm) function and spliting the string in half with the help of [strlen](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strlen.htm) to calculate the string's length.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    int x;

    printf("Pick the program that should be executed:\n");
    printf(" 1. Split text\n Enter an option:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    if (x == 1) {
        printf("Write the text you want to use:\n");
        char str[100];

        // -- Point 1 --
        // A
        //scanf("%s", str); 

        // B
        getchar();
        fgets(str, 100, stdin);
        // -------------

        printf("Input was: %s\n", str);

        int len = strlen(str);
        char *left, *right;
        left = malloc(len/2 + 1);
        right = malloc(len/2 + 1);

        memcpy(left, str, len/2);
        left[len/2] = 0;
        memcpy(right, str + len/2, len/2);
        right[len/2] = 0;

        // print the results
        printf("Original : %s\nLeft side: %s\nRight side: %s\n\n", str, left, right);

        // clean up
        free(left);
        free(right);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int len = strlen(str);` then `left = malloc(len/2);` (same for `right`) -- Question, "Where does the *nul-terminating* character get stored in both `left, right`?"